# how to create a string with self inside it

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function for some buttons. I don't want to create one for each button so  wrote this

```
def setSmValue (self, attr):
    selection = mc.ls(sl=True)
    lightShapes = [mc.pickWalk(shape, direction="down")[0] for shape in selection if mc.nodeType(mc.pickWalk(shape, direction="down")) in ['directionalLight','pointLight','spotLight','areaLight']]
    mc.select(selection, r=True)
    value = mc.textFieldButtonGrp(self.smapResolutionField, q=True, text=True) 
    for l in lightShapes:
        mc.setAttr('%s.%s' % (l, attr), float(value))
```

This is working but is not good for all the buttons. I would like to change

```
self.smapResolutionField
```

to something like

```
('self.%s' % attr)
```

I tryed all I could think about but seems like I don't understand too clearly the use of self :)

Any hint?

Thanks

EDIT: I probably forgot to mention that I'm using that command to query a textField (the user put the value there and I need to read it back)

Comment: Are you looking for `getattr(self, attr)`?

Comment: self is same as this object and 'self.%s' means you are treating it as a string

Comment: So `eval('self.%s' % attr)` does the trick too, but it's NOT recommended at any time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
getattr(self, attr)
```

to get it  :)

Comment: Thank you Felix for the quick answer but it's not working for me!
I'm trying to query a textField in a form and the object would be
    
    "self.smapResolutionField" while the attribute would be "text"
you can see that in my first post

Comment: I tryed that one too but still not working. This is the error I get

# Error: mrShadowMapChangerUI instance has no attribute 'smapResolution'
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "/home/users/luca/maya/scripts/mrShadowMapChanger.py", line 47, in __call__
#     return self.func( *self.args, **self.kwargs )
#   File "/home/users/luca/maya/scripts/mrShadowMapChanger.py", line 36, in setSmValue
#     value = mc.textFieldButtonGrp(getattr(self, attr), q=True, text=True)
# AttributeError: mrShadowMapChangerUI instance has no attribute 'smapResolution' #

Comment: So is your problem is at the *get* part, or the *set* part?

Comment: Emm.. Your object is `self.smapResolutionField` but your `attr` is `smapResolution`? Is this correct?

Comment: my bad :) It is working now! Sorry for the stupid error and thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`setattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr) and [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) built-ins.

To set:

```
setattr(self, 'smapResolutionField', some_value)
```

To get:

```
getattr(self, 'smapResolutionField')
```

Comment: Thanks Tadeck, but as I said on the other post this is not working for me :(
Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @nookie: I do not follow. If you are referring to `mc.setAttr('%s.%s' % (l, attr), float(value))`, then you are doing it wrong and it should be invoked in a way I have provided. What exactly are you trying to change / read? Please be more descriptive. Do you want to set/get `mc.self.smapResolutionField` property?